# Cannot install Python library with homebrew after upgrade to MacOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, cmake, clang, homebrew, macos-mojave

I am installing a python lib in Macosx Mojave 10.14.5 using homebrew.

It seems like clang is not aware of absolute header location. Like this is not correct path of isysroot:  -**mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -isysroot /SDKs/MacOSX.platform/MacOSX10.13.sdk**

The correct location for header is: **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk**.

I tried `brew doctor` and `brew audit`, but clang still points to 10.13 and in partial location.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
  -g -O2 \
  -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 \
  -isysroot SDKs/MacOSX.platform/MacOSX10.13.sdk \
  -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c1013.dir/testCCompiler.c.o \
  -c \
  /private/var/folders/d5/_y4xg4k91b5gllsppplwsd5m0000gn/T/pip-install-geb7zeba/dynet/build/py3.7-64bit/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
```

Error:

```
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/SDKs/MacOSX.platform/MacOSX10.13.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
```

Comment: Please include the original command you are running as well. And check this out: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85480/how-should-i-fix-my-homebrew-installation-after-upgrading-os-x